# colorMultiply not working on custom icons [SwiftUI]

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using colorMultiply on XCode's default icons, it seems to work fine but when using it on custom icons, it doesn't. Is there a workaround for this that works like Android Studio's **tint** property which caters for all images/icons?

```
 Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").colorMultiply(.red) //magnifyingglass is default provided XCode icon
```

works but

```
 Image("my_icon").colorMultiply(.red)
```

isn't working. My icons are png format.

Comment: It works with custom icons as well. Are you sure your custom icon has a color other than black? If it's black, try inverting it first like this: `Image("my_icon").colorInvert().colorMultiply(.blue)`

Comment: i've tried with colorInvert() but still doesn't work but my icons have always been back, let me try white

Comment: Do you want ```.foregroundColor()```? In SpriteKit, Images also have a ```.colorBlendFactor``` property to see how tinty they can be.

Comment: Works fine as-is with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. Do you use different Xcode? Do you see icon w/o colorMultiply? Can you add this icon to question?

Comment: i was using black ones, @Asperi, im also using XCode 11.4, i however didnt know the images had to be white

Comment: Do you mean completely filled black? But black is rgb:0,0,0 - anything multiplied by 0 is 0.

Comment: @Asperi exactly, i dont know why i expected that logic to work, just didn't think it through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who come across this, `Image("my_icon").colorMultiply(.red)` only works with white images - at least in my case. I was using black icons and colorMultiply wouldn't work but when i switched to white ones, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

One way you can handle this is to try inverting the image then applying the color multiply.

e.g.

```
Image("my_icon").colorInvert().colorMultiply(.red)
```

This takes the blacks of your image, makes them lighter, so the red color is visible.  Otherwise, you are simply contributing to greater black.